# Haskell Sudoku Solver - Random Block Coordinates Generator

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads, sudoku

I have a question regarding an assignment of mine. So I am supposed to implement the following using Haskell: "Write a program that generates Sudoku problems with three empty blocks. Is it also possible to generate Sudoku problems with four empty blocks?"

The random generators using IO aren't a problem, but the coordinates of the Sudoku puzzle are.. If I get for example an random integer (for example 3 (3rd block)), how can I then determine the coordinates of the random-given block? I have tried several approaches such as list comprehension, but the problem is setting the property of (x,y) - coordinates.

I would really appreciate if somebody could give me some hint.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can make this a bit more clear - is the problem getting 2 random numbers? (Well just use the RNG twice ... or something along the lines of `div` and `mod` - the opposite of `nrBlock = 3*y + x` is `y = div nrBlock 3` and `x = mod nrBlock 3`)

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't entirely clear, but if I understand it correctly then you can use something like this (nb: this actually needs a number between 0 and 8 inclusive, not 1 and 9)

```
blockCoords n = let
  [bx,by] = map (\f -> (n `f` 3) * 3) [mod,div]
  r t = map (+ t) [1,2,3]
  in [(x,y) | x <- r bx, y <- r by]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive on what you're asking in the question but I think a nice solution would be to use lenses. They're quite nice when you have data structures you want to index into.

For example you could create a record type for a block

```
Block = { _x :: Int
          _y :: Int }

$(makeLenses ''Block)
```

I believe the syntax is along those lines. I used lenses when I was making a minesweeper game and it made indexing the board incredibly simple.

Hope this helps!